# What's up with the voting pattern?

Tags: discussion

[How to increase push ups](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22577/how-to-increase-push-ups)

As best I can tell, it looks like the answers here are being consistently downvoted with few upvotes. I know that we have a fairly quiet community here, but this seems oddly consistent that the only people paying attention to this question are doing so to downvote the answers.

I'd take this to chat, but the last person to talk there was 22 days ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that people tend to be a lot more ready to downvote than to upvote. [I just stumbled across this question a few minutes ago](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16436/benefits-of-squatting-from-bottom-position-as-rest-position), and before I got there the answer had 10 up votes but the question itself only had 1.

It wasn't the best question ever, but it was certainly good enough to garner a decent answer that a lot of people found useful, which would never have happened if it wasn't for the person who asked in the first place. 10:1 is an absurd ratio, and you don't see things like that on the larger stackexchange sites (SO, etc).

The real shame about not upvoting is that we don't really promote new people. I saw an endocrinologist answer a question on here one time and I think I was the only upvote. The guy probably spent half an hour typing it up, it was educational and approachable. A single up vote.

There is a lot of junk that needs to be downvotes/closed with the quickness, but the lack of upvoting is a real shame.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone thought of introducing a few more badges? I ask as there's a **critic** badge for your first down vote, but nothing for your: 50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 700, 1000th down vote or ideally down votes in excess of up votes cast.

I'm sure some fun could be had allocating names to these new accolades ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a pattern of downvotes on this question. 2 of the 5 answers have a single downvote. Total: 4 upvotes, 2 downvotes.

Comment: At the time when I posted my question, the only votes up had been mine on other peoples' answers. The two downvoted answers were the two first ones, which were downvoted within a short time of their posting.